# Would Amazon S3 work as storage for sensor data streaming in from millions of endpoints?

Tags: amazon-s3, cassandra, sensors

I am looking for options for reliable (and speedy) storage for small amounts of sensor data that would be coming in from (getting optimistic here) millions of endpoints.
The scale I'm talking is 1M endpoints, each sending 100 bytes every minute. This data needs to be available for analysis shortly after this.
Additionally, this data will be kept for a few years and may exceed 100TB of total storage.

Is S3 the solution to this, or would I be better off hosting my own NoSQL cluster like Cassandra/MongoDB etc?

Please let me know if I have not specified any information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could. But, there are no query mechanisms nor any method of reading multiple objects in one request in S3. You would also not have any mechanism to inspect the data before it's written.

This might be a better idea:

- Have clients write sensor data onto a SQS queue
- Your application reads messages off the queue and writes the data into SimpleDB or other data store

It would de-couple receipt of the data, with any data load/storage phase.

Note that many Amazon services have a per-request charge. For SQS it's $0.01/10000 requests. If you want to have 1 million clients write one message each minute request charges alone would be over $40,000 a month. Doubling when taking reading the messages into account.

```
(((1000000 * (60*24*30)) / 10000) * $0.01) * 2 = $86,400
```

For S3, it's $0.01/1000 for POSTs (client writes), and $0.01/10000 GETs (reads). For 1 million clients your per-request charges alone could easily reach $500,000 per month.

Ultimately, at 1 million clients, you likely need to run your own receiving endpoints simply due to economic factors.

Comment: Great point about the economics.  What the OP asks is certainly feasible, but getting optimal costs is a different avenue that one encounters only with experience.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. The cost of this does seem very steep as against say if I was just collecting data on a ec2 based infrastructure where there is no per write cost (incoming data free). But does S3 even support a way to say, append to a data blob where I am collecting data for a single user? Or do I need to create one file for each data sample received? That would balloon out of control.. Comments?

Comment: @user393144 S3 is simple blob storage: there is no method to 'append' to an existing file. If your data is structured, I expect you will be much better served storing it in a database; either traditional relational or no-SQL (e.g. SimpleDB).

Comment: I just read about being able to use HBase that is backed by S3 as the filesystem. Now if S3 has no file append like capability, how can HBase use it as a filesystem? For e.g. what happens at S3 layer when I add a single new column to HBase?

Comment: @user393144 That would be a good question for the HBase community. But this fact remains: you do not interact with S3 like a traditional 'file system'. S3 is a key-value blob store accessed over HTTP.